# undefined instance when used in a <script>

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JavaScript class **Timer** which counts down to a future date. The constructor accepts a CSS selector and the date in question (a string), i.e., `new Timer('#timer',toTime)`. When invoked in a `<script>`, however, there seems to be a race condition. Consider the PHP snippet:

```
$toDate = date(DATE_ATOM, mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2024));  // Jan 1st, 2024
echo '<script type="text/javascript">', PHP_EOL;
echo "  window.t = new Timer('#timer', '$toDate')", PHP_EOL;
echo '</script>', PHP_EOL;
```

Looking at the `window` object in the console gives `t: undefined`. That said, if I set in the script `window.t = 1234`, such a value is found (`t: 1234`).

There seems to be a race condition when using `new` within a `<script>`. Does anyone know how to fix it?

It is worth noting that the timer shows on the page just fine, but I don't have a handle on the JavaScript Timer object and I need to execute some other methods, like stopping the countdown.

Comment: You may want to look at the rendered source in the browser. PHP runs before the page is sent to the browser, javascript after, so as long as the script section is rendered correctly, it's not an issue with PHP.

Comment: `new Timer()` can't return anything other than a `Timer` object, it can't return `undefined`. The only way this can happen is if the assignment isn't being executed at all.

Comment: I hope you output this code to be _inside_ html and not _outside_? Can you show final rendered HTML (relevant part only)

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake! In reality, the **Timer** class has methods to count up, down, or just be a clock, which I omitted for the sake of brevity. The relevant call is:

`window.t = new Timer('#timer', '$toDate').countDown()`

Those methods (`countDown` in this case) were not returning `this` and therefore the return was `undefined`.